# Why xdebug 3 is not loaded?

Tags: php, xdebug-3

I have restarted nginx and php7.4-fpm.

xdebug 3 looks like is installed based on this:

```
root@darius-Vostro-5481:/home/darius/Private/Projects/vop7# apt search xdebug
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
php-xdebug/bionic,now 3.0.1+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
  Xdebug Module for PHP

php5.6-xdebug/bionic,now 3.0.1+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Xdebug Module for PHP

php7.0-xdebug/bionic,now 3.0.1+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Xdebug Module for PHP

php7.1-xdebug/bionic,now 3.0.1+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
  Xdebug Module for PHP

php7.2-xdebug/bionic,now 3.0.1+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Xdebug Module for PHP

php7.3-xdebug/bionic,now 3.0.1+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Xdebug Module for PHP

php7.4-xdebug/bionic,now 3.0.1+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Xdebug Module for PHP

php8.0-xdebug/bionic,now 3.0.1+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Xdebug Module for PHP
```

Ini directories from phpinfo():

Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/15-xml.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-dom.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-ffi.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-imagick.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-posix.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-redis.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xsl.ini, /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-zip.ini

/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini content:

```
# xdebug 3 -          
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so
```

I do not know how to check if this is the right file. They write in the docs:

> Add the following line to php.ini:
>
> zend_extension=/wherever/you/put/it/xdebug

How can I know where I put? :) It was installed by install command, it put where it put :) In that directory there is no file without .so . I just used similar directory and file name to what was xdebug 2.

phpinfo() does not show xdebug loaded.

Adding xdebug_info(); to file crashes the page - probably this function is not defined.

Comment: I have a feeling there may be a issue with XDEBUG3 on PHP7.4. I can get it running on PHP8 but not on 7.4 or 7.3 although I am using windows

Comment: @Darius.V 1) Xdebug 3 is available for PHP 7.1 and newer ONLY. 2) for PHP **7.4** the folder should be `20190902`. `20200930` is for PHP **8.0**.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sounds like you have downloaded wrong Xdebug build. Works fine here with PHP 7.4. Show top of the `php -i` output for your PHP 7.3/7.4 -- to see what version those are. There are TS and NTS builds and each either for x86 (32 but) or x64 bit. If it's Apache then you most likely need TS build. If it's IIS then NTS.

Comment: Hi @LazyOne Anything is possible I guess. I am aware of the TS and NTS options I am definitely a TS user. Oh must have been one of those days yesterday, now it works just fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LazyOne said

> for PHP 7.4 the folder should be 20190902

So setting in ini file

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
```

loads xdebug 3 for Php 7.4 . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is just because you used "#" for comments instead of ";"
(Stupidly enough)